# JS and regular expression for replacing everthing inside double = mark

Tags: javascript, regex, github-pages

I am trying to write a blog on GitHub pages. But the GFM does not support highlight text like typora does. What I want to do is to match everything (including line breaks) in between a pair of "==". So the following text should be selected

```
Edit the ==Expression=
== & T==sa==ext to see matches.
```

and changed to

```
Edit the <span class="highlight">Expression=
</span> & T<span class="highlight">sa</span>ext to see matches.
```

What I am asking is that

1. What regular expression should I use to match? I got `={2}[^=]*={2}` but that's not right.
2. Is there any simple js I can do the replacement? I want my website to use as little JS as possible.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this pretty cleanly with back references and the `s` flag:

```js
let str = `Edit the ==Expression=
== & T==sa==ext to see matches.`

let tags = str.replace(/==(.*?)==/gs, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>')
console.log(tags)
```

On the chance you are working in an environment where the `s` flag doesn't yet work you can also use `[\s\S]` to match the text including line breaks:

```js
let str = `Edit the ==Expression=
== & T==sa==ext to see matches.`

let tags = str.replace(/==([\s\S]*?)==/g, "<span>$1</span>")
console.log(tags)
```

Comment: looks like *dotAll* flag is not supported in FireFox yet. It throws a **SyntaxError**

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that as well @mrReiha. Hopefully soon — it's in Node and works in webkit.

Comment: Ah, I knew there was going to be a way to use capturing groups, I just couldn't figure out how to use the syntax for referring to them in the string. Nice answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot for a answer! Sorry to ask again, but is there any way to provide an "esacpe"? For example, It should parse `==where the euqal sign are next to text==` but leave `== those equal signs that are surounded by spaces ==` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go! This is a solution using super secret regex replace function techniques.

```js
var testString = "Edit the ==Expression=\n== & T==sa==ext to see matches.";
console.log(testString);
console.log(testString.replace(/={2}([^=]=?)*={2}/g, function(match){
    return match.replace("==","<span class=\"highlight\">").replace("==","</span>");
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following regex:

```
={2}(.*?)(?<!==)={2}
```

use a back reference to `\1` and surround it with `<span class="highlight">` and `</span>`. (however [Mark Meyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3874623/mark-meyer) solution is more direct and better as Lookbehinds are only available in browsers supporting ECMA2018 standard)

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/UaFVeh/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the entire solution to my question: replace `==` surounded text with `<span class="highlight"> </span>`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
  .highlight {
    background-color: yellow
  }
</style>

<body>
  <p>
    == asddac == awdawd = awda ==wad == ==d==
  </p>
</body>
<script>
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/==([\s\S]*?)==/g, "<span class=\"highlight\">$1</span>");
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This uses lazy quantifiers and backreferences.

`==(.*?)==` [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/eEn7AM/1)